# How to know who pushed the code to git in jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

I got a error message in jenkins console output & I want to report-mail to that person who committed the code? But how do I find him in jenkins console output?

Comment: Person who pushed and the person who committed the code is not necessarily the same. Which one do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the e-mail address of the commiter with the following command:

```
git show -s --format='%aw'
```

If you have installed git on your Jenkins (which I truly believe) you can simply execute this as bash / sh command or using Jenkins' `echo` if you want to display it. Using groovy you can even put the e-mail into a variable.

```
...
script
{
    commiter = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git show -s --format='%aw')
    echo "Person who commited: ${commiter}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply... But I don't have access to backend server/ cli... So how to know who committed/pushed from console output itself ... ? Thanks

Comment: You can see the commit id in the sourcode checkout usually. With the id you could check the commiter. I don't think the usual code checkout in Jenkins prints the commiter.

Comment: `git show -s --format='%aw'` shows `%aw` in stdout. Did you mean `%ae`? The correct command should be `git show -s --foramt='%ae'`, source: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats